# How to the full base url of the site with Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to get all of the base url of the site in my twig extension:

```
$this->service_container->get('request')->getBaseUrl()
```

gives me a lot but the host is missing...

another method maybe to get everything or one to get the host ?

Goal : have this :

```
http://my_host/request_base_url
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$scheme = $request->getScheme();
$host = $request->getHttpHost();
$base = sprintf('%s://%s', $scheme, $host);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how im using this code  to get complete base url .

```
public function test($request){
 $baseurl = $request->getScheme() . '://' . $request->getHttpHost() . $request->getBasePath() ;
}
```